# snmp network simulator like ciscos packet tracer?

Tags: networking

Im looking for a network simulator similar to ciscos packet tracer but does more types of devices then just ciscos. Anyone know of a such program? Im not wanting to actually send fake traffic over my network but emulate a fake network within one computer.
I would give you two points if I could for anyone that lists open source links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found GNS3 and it works great and can even send out fake packets on a virtualized network or the fake network limited to the gui in the software.

Found GNS3 except I can not figure out how to add a pc to configure.

Anyone know how to do so? They list a tutorial but not one with virtual pc or virtual box.

Edit:
heres the GNS3 website to download their program:
http://www.GNS3.net